# Как из Servlet'а прочитать асинхронно сообщение из JMS

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet, jms

Собственно при традиционном чтении сообщения в сервлете

```
    boolean goodByeReceiver = false;
    mSc = getServletContext();

    JMSContext jmsContext = connectionFactory.createContext();
    JMSConsumer jmsConsumer = jmsContext.createConsumer(queue);

    message = jmsConsumer.receiveBody(String.class);
    mSc.log("receiver message from queue: " + message);
```

возникает неприятный эффект что если очередь пуста, то сервлет зависает.
При использовании слушателя столкнулся с проблемой получая 500 ошибку с сообщением в логах что метод слушателя нельзя использовать в

> This method may not be called in a Java EE web or EJB container

Сам код у меня (который не работает) такой:

```
        JMSContext jmsContext = connectionFactory.createContext();
        JMSConsumer jmsConsumer = jmsContext.createConsumer(queue);

        AsynchMessageListener aml = new AsynchMessageListener(mSc);
        jmsConsumer.setMessageListener(aml);
        mSc.log("into servlet :" + aml.getStrMessage());
```

Код слушателя такой:

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;

    strMessage = "";

    try {
        strMessage = textMessage.getText();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        strMessage = "exception detected";
    }

    mSc.log("into listener" + strMessage);
}
```

Собственно вопрос, куда копать и как

Comment: Должен ли сервлет дождаться мессаги и показать что-то в браузере или просто запустить запустить фоновую задачу и сразу вернуть ответ, не дожидаясь мессаги?

Comment: Если проблема в том, что сервлет зависает, и это побудило искать асинхронное решение, то вместо `jmsConsumer.receive()` можно воспользоваться `jmsConsumer.receive(timeout)` - сервлет зависнет на timeout миллисекунд или `jmsConsumer.receiveNoWait()` - сервлет не зависнет вообще. В том и другом случае, если не будет получено мессаги (в течении таймаута в первом случае или немедленно во втором) вернут null. Почаще заглядывайте в javadoc. Там кстати и `This method may not be called in a Java EE web or EJB container` задокументировано.

Comment: @Sergey Спасибо за ответ! Сейчас доберусь до работы и сделаю как вы сказали...

Comment: @Sergey а вот такой вопрос, я сейчас  стал использовать функцию ReceiveBodyNoWait() - но столкнулся с проблемой что она считывает только первое значение и все. При повторном запуске она нечего не возвращает...

Comment: Что значит `первое значение`? Первое сообщение (точнее тело первого сообщения)? А второе сообщение типа не видит? Как это проявляется: возвращает null или кидается исключениями?

Comment: @Sergey первое сообщение.возвращает null...

Comment: Значит сообщение ещё не доступно или `jmsConsumer` уже закрыт к тому времени. А может вторая мессага и не отправляется вовсе?

Comment: @Sergey вот мой код для посыла сообщений   String message = "100";
  jmsProducer.send(queue, message);
  message = "101";
  jmsProducer.send(queue, message);
  message = "102";
  jmsProducer.send(queue, message);
  message = "103";
  jmsProducer.send(queue, message);
  message = "104";
  jmsProducer.send(queue, message);
  message = "bye";
  jmsProducer.send(queue, message);

Comment: @Sergey вот для того он замечательно работает   while(!goodByeReceiver){
   message = jmsConsumer.receiveBody(String.class);
   if (message != null){
    mSc.log("receiver message from queue: " + message);
    if (message.equals("bye")){
     goodByeReceiver = true;
    }
   }
   
  }

Comment: Может отправка не поспевает за приемом. При отправке мессага сначала сохраняется в базе очереди сообщений, какое-то время на этом теряется. А получатель в это время не ждёт ничего. Смотрит прямо сейчас ничего нет и на те null. Попробуйте метод с таймаутом: `jmsConsumer.receiveBody(String.class, millis);`

Comment: @Sergey тоже самое :(

Comment: таймаут какой? может увеличить. минуты полторы. (60 + 30) * 1000 за глаза хватит:)

Comment: @Sergey ну в цикле то все ок и без таймаутов ....